# Body Parallels to the Creation

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, creation, parts-of-the-body, allegory-mashal

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99546/body-parallels-to-the-mishkan).

Some commentaries viewed maaseh bereishis to be the literal description of the creation, and some interpret it in an allegorical fashion. I recall hearing somewhere that several creations mentioned in there were allegories to body parts. Does anyone know where is the source(s) for this, given that this does not seems to be a new idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (a) source is [Avos d’Rebbi Nassan 31:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D%27Rabbi_Natan.31.3):

> אף כך הקב״ה יהא שמו הגדול מבורך לעולם ולעולמי עולמים בחכמתו ובתבונתו ברא את כל העולם כולו וברא את השמים ואת הארץ עליונים ותחתונים. ויצר באדם כל מה שברא בעולמו.
>
> So, too, Hashem, in His wisdom and understanding, created the whole world, and he created the heavens and the earth, the upper realm and the lower realm, and he fashioned in man corresponding to everything He created.
>
> ברא חורשים בעולם וברא חורשים באדם זה שערות של אדם. ברא חיה רעה בעולם ברא חיה רעה באדם זה (בני מעיו) של אדם. (ברא קורצין בעולם וברא קורצין באדם זה אזניו של אדם). ברא ריח בעולם ברא ריח באדם זה חוטמו של אדם. חמה בעולם חמה באדם זה אורו של אדם. מים סרוחים בעולם מים סרוחים באדם זהו מימי חוטמו של אדם. מים מלוחים בעולם מים מלוחים באדם זהו דמעות של עינים. נחלים בעולם נחלים באדם אלו דמעות חומות בעולם חומות באדם אלו שפתותיו של אדם. דלתות בעולם דלתות באדם זה שיניו של אדם. (רקיעים בעולם רקיעים באדם זה לשונו של אדם).מים מתוקים בעולם מים מתוקים באדם זהו רוקו של אדם. לסתות בעולם לסתות באדם זה לחייו של אדם. מגדלים בעולם מגדלים באדם זה צוארו של אדם. etc..

The Braisa continues with an extensive list of parallels between the world and the human body.

Comment: Kudos for finding! I added some text to give an illustration of metaphors the Midrash uses. That's about the level of scientific research of those times. :(

Comment: @AlBerko It’s a Midrash. It’s not meant to be scientific, or necessarily literal, but to impart lessons.

Comment: Right, I know, I'm just saying about their knowledge of anatomy and biology - for a nation that received the masterbook seem odd.

Comment: What do we learn from such a Midrash nowadays? Does it help us in medicine or anything else? For me it sounds like Rorschach blots - everyone interpreting it to his own imagination.